# Unable to match currency symbols using python regex

Tags: python, regex

```
l_test_word = 'in €'
print(l_test_word)

if re.match(pattern=r'[£$€]+', string=l_test_word):

    print("Match")
else:

    print("No Match")
```

I am trying to match if a string contains curency symbols.
The code snippet above when runs returning "No Match".
Unable to figure out why? I am using python 2.7.13. 
Thanks.

Comment: `re.match` only matches at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score -1):

You're using `match` instead of `search` as Rakesh correctly said.

If you want to use `match` your code should be:

```
import re

l_test_word = 'in €'
print(l_test_word)

if re.match(pattern=r'.*?[£$€]+', string=l_test_word):

    print("Match")
else:

    print("No Match")
```

Note that I added .*? at the beginning of the pattern.

Cheers.

**EDIT:**
Just to avoid a misunderstanding. Obviously this is not the best way to find a symbol like "€". `re.search` is better for searching, `re.match` is better to match a string from the beginning. The .*? is only a lazy workaround.